# Any way to trigger QCOM Mass storage mode in TWRP?

Tags: twrp

The phone has a Qualcomm MSM8996 SoC (Snapdragon 820) and a eMMC 5.1
QFIL Says something like this:

"download fail:sahara fail:qsaharaserver fail:process fail"

I have a TWRP image for my phone, will the [mass storage script](https://github.com/WOA-Project/SurfaceDuo-Guides/blob/main/InstallWindows/ReinstallWindows-SurfaceDuo1.md) from Surface Duo work?
On this phone (With W10M) it could be possible by placing the x.efi file to specific location, and selecting USB Mass Storage Mode in boot menu.

Comment: Why do you think a script for installing ARM Windows would work on an Android phone? The "lower layers" (bootloader and so on) are totally different from a regular PC.

Comment: It's not a windows install script. Here's the code:


`#!/sbin/bash
echo 0xEF > /config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceClass; echo 0x02 > /config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceSubClass; echo 0x01 > /config/usb_gadget/g1/bDeviceProtocol
ln -s /config/usb_gadget/g1/functions/mass_storage.0/ /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/
echo /dev/block/sda > /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/mass_storage.0/lun.0/file
echo 0 > /config/usb_gadget/g1/configs/b.1/mass_storage.0/lun.0/removable
sh -c 'echo > /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC; echo a600000.dwc3 > /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC' &`
There's nothing related to Windows.

Comment: The script title is `Reinstall Windows on Surface Duo 1` thus it is a script for installing Windows and this means the hardware is a PC, not an Android device. The CPU is irrelevant for an install script, the system environment makes the computer not the CPU.